# Unable to view Prometheus metrics produced by Spring Boot Micrometer in browser

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I'm currently unable to view the metrics exposed by the Spring Boot Actuator endpoint as they are being **downloaded** rather than displayed in the browser.

On examination of the response headers, I noted that the returned response content type is: `application/openmetrics-text` which is perhaps why the browser is defaulting to downloading the content.

Is there any way to "force" the endpoint to return a `text/plain` content type in the response. (without writing serve-side interceptors etc)?

Comment: Can you provide the Accept header request please ?

Comment: @GianniAzizi Yes sure: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9

Comment: Thanks. Which version of spring boot actuator are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot Actuator: 2.5.5 and I've tried almost every version of micrometer-registry-prometheus from 1.4.0 upwards.

Answer (score 0):

The `spring-boot` github project's [issue 28446](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28446) could possibly answer your question.

To fix it, try the following steps:

1. Avoid using spring-boot **version 2.5.6**. My version 2.7.4 works fine as follows:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

2. Re-check your project's imported **modules**( those shown in your Intellij IDEA's **external libraries**). Validate the spring-boot libraries' **version**. There may be some old versioned libraries not updated.